# Different properties in one list

Tags: c#, list, object, properties

i have a class that mades me sick.
I get this data from my db, and just want to manipulate things and bring it back.
The class that get my nervs broken:

```
public class Part
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool horizontal { get; set; }
    public bool @abstract { get; set; }
    public bool orientationChangable { get; set; }
    public int? shared { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "alu")]
    public bool alu { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "paint")]
    public bool? paint { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "glue")]
    public bool? glue { get; set; }
    public List<> install { get; set; } // Problem here
    public List<> replace { get; set; } // And here
    public int index { get; set; }
```

An Object can look like this:

```
"install": [
        false,
        false,
        false,
        ""
      ],
      "replace": [
        false,
        false,
        false,
        ""
      ],

or different one like this:

"install": [
        false,
        2,
        ""
      ],
      "replace": [
        false,
        false,
        3
      ],
```

I marked the properties with the issue. In this properties can be booleans, strings and/or an integers.

I tried to make `List<dynamic>`, `List<object>` but nothing works, how do i handle a list that contains different types ?

A solution would be to give a empty list back, but then i even dont know how to describe the properties to get it work. Any Solutions ?

Comment: You say you've tried `List<object>`, but you haven't told us what happened when you *did* try it. What failed?

Comment: if i set it to List<object> it generates a whole part for any property in the install list. So i would have 3 times the roof, but i only want one.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "whole part" - it would really help if you could edit your question to give a concrete example. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for suggestions about writing a clear question.

Comment: You see my class Part in my example. In the part there are the lists i mean. If i change it the way you said, it creates a whole part for each property in the install list which is inside my part class.

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify the question - instead, give a full concrete example *in the question*, with either the incoming JSON and what the deserialized objects look like, or code to create objects and then the serialized JSON. At the moment it's still very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Type parameters `T` and `U` and can replace them with types while initializing and declaring the object.

Part class code

```
public class Part<T, U>
{
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool horizontal { get; set; }
        public bool @abstract { get; set; }
        public bool orientationChangable { get; set; }
        public int? shared { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "alu")]
        public bool alu { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "paint")]
        public bool? paint { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "glue")]
        public bool? glue { get; set; }
        public List<T> install { get; set; } // Problem solved by using T
        public List<U> replace { get; set; } // And also this one
        public int index { get; set; }
    }
```

I have initialized it with some random data.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Part<dynamic, dynamic> p = new Part<dynamic, dynamic>()
            {
                name = "test",
                horizontal = true,
                @abstract = true,
                orientationChangable = false,
                shared = 12,
                count = 20,
                size = 23,
                alu = true,
                paint = true,
                glue = true,
                install = new List<dynamic>
                {
                    "Hello" , 34, 23, 34, 23
                },
                replace = new List<dynamic>
                {
                    234, true, "test3"
                },
                index = 234
            };

            var jsonObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

The jsonObject has the data.

Comment: This does not help when the OP shows each list having different objects in it

Comment: @Jamiec Thank you! I haven't recognized the question very well. Now check it again! I think now it will work.

Comment: Now theres no point having generic parameters on `Part`

Comment: That works for me, it creates exactly the solution i need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way to deal with a list of different types is to go with the lowest common type, which is likely to be `object` in this case (`dynamic` will *also* work but gives you no discernable benefit over `object`). Here is an example of this working:

```
var input = "[false,false,123,\"foo\"]";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(input);
foreach(var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LOYEWa

So your class would have to define these 2 lists as `List<object>` for deserialization to work

```
public class Part
{
    ...
    public List<object> install { get; set; } // No problem here
    public List<object> replace { get; set; } // Nor here
    ...
}
```

Comment: @DennisHorstkamp no, I was just demonstrating that you can parse that string array to a `List<object>` - all you need to do is make your property say `public List<object> install { get; set; }` as I put at the bottom

Comment: It wasn't working for me, but i appreciate your help